# Replace text content from xml and push back in golng

Tags: xml, go

For a given XML document, I want to extract all the text content exclude some certain tags and do some transformation with the content and push the modified content back to the position where they are exacted.

I tried to generate a tree(saying a nested `map`) for the document, and after the transformation, build the document by the tree again.

However I have not find any library I can used in golang.

Is this possible?

---

update:

The structure of the xml document are not fixed.

Comment: Have you looked at `encoding/xml`? You could define a type that models the structure of the xml document, unmarshal the xml into a value of that type with `encoding/xml`, manipulate the contents of the value, and then marshal the value back into xml.

Comment: The structure of the xml is not fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically there are three approaches I can think of:

- Define a set of Go types matching the elements of your XML document.
  Then unmarshal the document into a hierarchy of these variables.
  Then apply to these variables whatever updates are needed and
  marshal them back to an XML document.

  The upside of this approach is that it's "standard" (requires
  just the `encoding/xml` standard package) and is "data-driven".

  The downsides are many:

  - It may tedious to code up a set of types.
  - It may be hard to make work for the cases
    when your documents have dynamic structure, or the cases
    when you really just want to consider *all* elements and their text nodes.
- Do ["SAX-style" processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML):
  `encoding/xml` allows you to "step-through"
  each XML node — as the parser decodes them.

  So it's possible to create a `Decoder` reading the source document
  and an `Encoder` — producing the resulting one.
  Each token decoded by the decoder gets encoded by the encoder
  either right away or after certain processing on your side
  (which may result in adding more tokens).

  Unfortunately, if you need to maintain some context between
  visiting different tokens (so, say, only modify text nodes of the
  elements which are on certain paths in the document),
  [this is not doable easily](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/22290#issuecomment-363235274)
  (though still possible, of course).
- Use a full-blown [XSLT processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT).

  You may look at [this](https://godoc.org/github.com/jbowtie/ratago/xslt).

Comment: We have a log of xml to be processed, and some of them are `html`s, is there an alternative for html parsing?

Comment: [Yes](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html). Also see [this](https://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery).